# Persist kendo treeview expanded state on page load

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I'm using kendo treeview. I need to persist the treeview expanded state after navigating to a treeview link.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {@class="demo-section",@style="height:700px;" })
    .DataTextField("Name").DataUrlField("Name").DataUrlField("URL").ExpandAll(true)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("GetUserMenue", "UserManagement")
        )

    )

)


public ActionResult GetUserMenue(int? id)
        {
            repUser = new UserManagementRepository();

            List<UserMenue> model = repUser.getMenue(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));

            if (!id.HasValue)
            {
                var emp = from e in model
                          select new
                          {
                              id = e.PermissionID,
                              Name = e.Name,
                              URL=e.URL,
                              hasChildren = e.hasChildren
                          };

                return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                List<UserMenue> modelChild1 = repUser.getMenuLevel2(id);

                var emp = from e in modelChild1
                          select new
                          {
                              id = e.PermissionID,
                              Name = e.Name,
                              URL = e.URL

                          };

                return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }


            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here u go [Doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/how-to/persist-expanded-state)

Main two functions:

```
function saveExpanded() {
  var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
  var expandedItemsIds = {};
  treeview.element.find(".k-item").each(function () {
    var item = treeview.dataItem(this);
    if (item.expanded) {
        expandedItemsIds[item.id] = true;
    }
  });
  Cookies.set('expanded', kendo.stringify(expandedItemsIds));
}

function setExpanded(data, expanded) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (expanded[data[i].id]) {
      data[i].expanded = true;
    }
    if (data[i].items && data[i].items.length) {
      setExpanded(data[i].items, expanded);
    }
  }
}
```

Just make sure u have referenced this jquery [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to use $.cookie function

Comment: Telerik being Telerik, URL moved:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/integration/persist-expanded-state

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 You can use `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()` methods when tree items are expanding or collapsing
Save tree items states in history states:

```
history.pushState({
    expanded: [...]
}, 'sometitle', '?expanded=' + ...);
```

For restore tree items states You must handle `window.onpopstate` event

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    restoreTreeItemsState(event.expanded); // your function that restores tree items states
}
```

Сheck reason of tree items state change while handling expand event. If tree items expands from your `restoreTreeItemsState` function, no history changes needed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

In old browsers You can use `window.location.hash`.
I don't use them, but it has similar functionality and more dificult than html5 history permforming